# Reducing the similar like queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have these four similar like queries:

```
        $products=Product::orderBy('views','desc')->with('category')->get();  //----1
        $mostviews=Product::orderBy('views','desc')->limit(10)->get();        //----2
        $show=Product::orderBy('views','desc')->with('category')
                                                    ->with('user')
                                                    ->with('productbrand.brand')                                        
                                                    ->first();                      //----3

        $shows=Product::orderBy('views','desc')->limit(20)
                                                     ->with('category')
                                                     ->with('user')
                                                     ->with('productbrand.brand')                                        
                                                     ->get();                       //----4
```

but for different purposes.

1. to get all products with categories.
2. to get 10 products
3. to get one product with categories, users, and brand
4. to get 20 products with categories, users, and brand

How can the queries be reduced?

Comment: Why do you want to combine the queries? are they all called in the same method or operation?

Comment: @AngadDubey trying to reduce the queries if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create all those variables. Just do this:

```
$products = Product::orderBy('views','desc')
                   ->with('category', 'user', 'productbrand.brand')
                   ->get();
```

After you got the data, use this variable. But I would also recommend you to not use `take()` method if you have product descriptions and/or specifications in DB. Because if you'll do this, it can easily take all memory. The thing is each [`take()` will create new collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-take).

You can use `$products` without creating new collections or variables:

```
// Show:
{{ $products->first()->id }}

// Most views:
@foreach ($products as $product)
    @if ($loop->iteration > 10)
        @break
    @endif

    {{ $product->something }}
@endforeach

// Shows:
@foreach ($products as $product)
    @if ($loop->iteration > 20)
        @break
    @endif

    {{ $product->something }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like,

```
$po= Product::orderBy('views','desc');
$products=$po->with('category')->get();  //---1
$mostviews=$po->limit(10)->get();        //---2
$shows=$po->limit(20)
          ->with('category')
          ->with('user')
          ->with('productbrand.brand')                 
          ->get(); 

$show=$shows[0];                      //----3
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller

```
$products = Product::orderBy('views','desc')->with(['category','user','productbrand.brand'])->get();

return view('product.list',compact('products'));
```

In your View

```
$all = $products;
$mostViews = $products->take(10);
$show = $products->first();
$shows=  $products->take(20);
```